# Is there a lubuntu 18.10 partitioning tool like "disks"? I don't find it in the menu

Tags: partitioning, 18.10

I have installed gparted, which shows only one of two hds. I don't know whether it has got to do with gparted or with my system. Where is the standard "disks" program in 18.10? Or is it named differently and I simply fail to see it?

Comment: Note: 18.10 will be [EOL by tomorrow](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/07/ubuntu-18-10-end-of-life), you should upgrade to 19.04.

Comment: KDE Partition Manager

Comment: And the upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 shouldn't be problematic (unlike the 18.04 > 18.10 one).

Comment: Thanks for this info, which I also got to another question yesterday. Frankly, I don't understand this policy really. If I have reason to stick with an older version (and there can be numerous reasons, such as old HW) I want to be able to ask about issues. I am a bit concerned, however, that some old package repositories are no more functional (why? Is it a matter of too much server space?) and that I frequently have to find ways to get what I need in some much less practical and more tedious ways. What about a section (and repos) for outdated versions? Why omit functioning solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just install "standard disks program" on Lubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I have done so, but to no avail. They have installed, but do not appear in the menu. Strange, really, the more because everything else about administration can be found there.

Comment: you can still run it from terminal. it will either be `gnome-disk-utility` or `gnome-disks` from there

Comment: BTW I found "disks" in the file managers "applications" tab, under "System" - but it does not appear in the menu itself. Somehow it remains hidden. It is also visible when I open the menu with alacarte, but thats it then. Strange! But as long as I have it reachable somewhere, that should suffice.

Comment: Awesome. this solution works properly.

Answer (score 4):

KDE Partition Manager

[image]

If you haven't seen it before, look up the page on the Lubuntu manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.1/3.1.7/kde_partitionmanager.html

Comment: fyi:  *this picture is from my running system, which was upgraded from 18.10 awhile back..*

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I do not find this program in the menu. Besides, I think I have LXQt. Perhaps this is a reason?

Comment: KDE is Qt, like LXQt is - which is why it is used.   I'm no longer running 18.10, which may mean you have to install it first (muon or discover - https://manual.lubuntu.me/4/Installing_Updating_and_Removing_Software.html)

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your answer and comments! I will try to install it.

I don't know exactly whether you got the points, since I have less than 15 reputation? .. but I tried! ;-)